# Using generated source or src-gen folder in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, code-generation, greendao, generated-code

My project my directory looks like this:

```
-project
  -someModule
  -mainProjectModule
    -src
      -main
        -java
          (all of my code)
```

I am trying to add a src-gen folder so it will look like this:

```
-project
  -someModule
  -mainProjectModule
    -src
      -main
        -java
          (all of my code)
    -src-gen
      -main
        -java
          (all of my generated code)
```

My generated code is in the same package as my non generated code. How can I make the /src-gen/main/java folder turn blue in Android Studio, and what do I need to put in my gradle to get this to build properly? I currently have this in my gradle and it doesn't seem to work:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src-gen/main/java']
    }
}
```

I have also tried manually editing the mainProjectModule.iml file to add the /src-gen/main/java folder as source, and it will turn blue, but it will automatically change back after several seconds.

Comment: Is the source generated via the build script, or is it generated through some other method?

Comment: I have 2 different generated sources. One is greendao (which comes from running separate module within the project. The other is google app engine endpoints which comes from a completely different project altogether. If I simply put these generated sources directly into src/main/java it works, but id rather separate them.

Comment: That syntax works for me. Is your `sourceSets` block inside your `android` block? If so, what version of Android Studio are you running?

Comment: Wow. I had sourceSets outside the android block. I moved it and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Great, added as an official answer with a little more explanation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `sourceSets` block needs to be inside the `android` block for Android build files. Note that this is different from plain Java builds, where that block goes at the top level:

```
android {
    ...
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src-gen/main/java']
        }
    }
}
```

As you've seen, editing the .iml files directly doesn't work for long -- those get overwritten every time Android Studio syncs the Gradle files with the project, which is somewhat often.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you take a look at my question, please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24578939/android-studio-canonical-way-to-include-a-code-generation-task